Pyodbc auto running CREATE PROCEDURE
I am connecting to a SQL Server using pyodbc - nothing fancy.
I have been flagged by a DBA that I have long running queries on the DB, however, I know the query I am running takes between 1-3 seconds long because if I run it in SSMS it takes this long.
When we added a trace to the DB, it seems there are two queries being executed. The below query seems to be auto running by pyodbc somehow, which I think is a driver initialisation maybe?
create procedure sys.sp_datatype_info_100  (      @data_type int = 0,      @ODBCVer tinyint = 2  )  as      declare @mintype int      declare @maxtype int        set @ODBCVer = isnull(@ODBCVer, 2)      if @ODBCVer < 3 -- includes ODBC 1.0 as well          set @ODBCVer = 2      else          set @ODBCVer = 3        if @data_type = 0      begin          select @mintype = -32768          select @maxtype = 32767      end      else      begin          select @mintype = @data_type          select @maxtype = @data_type      end        select          TYPE_NAME           = v.TYPE_NAME,          DATA_TYPE           = v.DATA_TYPE,          PRECISION           = v.PRECISION,          LITERAL_PREFIX      = v.LITERAL_PREFIX,          LITERAL_SUFFIX      = v.LITERAL_SUFFIX,          CREATE_PARAMS       = v.CREATE_PARAMS,          NULLABLE            = v.NULLABLE,          CASE_SENSITIVE      = v.CASE_SENSITIVE,          SEARCHABLE          = v.SEARCHABLE,          UNSIGNED_ATTRIBUTE  = v.UNSIGNED_ATTRIBUTE,          MONEY               = v.MONEY,          AUTO_INCREMENT      = v.AUTO_INCREMENT,          LOCAL_TYPE_NAME     = v.LOCAL_TYPE_NAME,          MINIMUM_SCALE       = v.MINIMUM_SCALE,          MAXIMUM_SCALE       = v.MAXIMUM_SCALE,          SQL_DATA_TYPE       = v.SQL_DATA_TYPE,          SQL_DATETIME_SUB    = v.SQL_DATETIME_SUB,          NUM_PREC_RADIX      = v.NUM_PREC_RADIX,          INTERVAL_PRECISION  = v.INTERVAL_PRECISION,          USERTYPE            = v.USERTYPE        from          sys.spt_datatype_info_view v        where          v.DATA_TYPE between @mintype and @maxtype and          v.ODBCVer = @ODBCVer        order by 2, 12, 11, 20  

Q: Has anyone seen this before and know anything more about it? Is it possible to disable this?
I am using simple code, sample below.
import pyodbc

conn_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=%SERVER%;DATABASE=%DATABASE%;Trusted_Connection=yes;MultiSubnetFailover=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;"
sql = "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM MY_DB"

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
res = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
conn.close()


I'd suggest talking with your DBA a little more to better understand the situation and clear up any miscommunications. e.g.: Python doesn't create sys.sp_datatype_info_100, that's a system procedure that's built into every SQL Server database since probably SQL Server 2008 days.

If you look at your traces a little more closely you'll probably notice that for every new connection the ODBC Driver executes exec [sys].sp_datatype_info_100 <number>,@ODBCVer=4 with numbers 12, -9, -3 and 93, so that it can determine what support the targeted SQL Server has for the varchar, nvarchar/sysname, varbinary, and smalldatetime/datetime/datetime2 data types.

Thanks @AlwaysLearning do you have any references that I can site at all please?

And if you can cite any references, I would be happy to accept that as an answer!

No references, I'm sorry, since sys.sp_datatype_info_100 is an undocumented system procedure. But you can cetainly create a brand new database for yourself, e.g.: CREATE DATABASE Demo; and then in SSMS immediately expand Databases > Demo > Programmability > Stored Procedures > System Stored Procedures to see that sys.sp_datatype_info_100 is already present before Python has ever connected.

Most drivers have some kind of startup code that's being run to fetch the metadata they need. Why does this query bother you?

Not to mention that the procedure you say it is "creating" (which in your question has invalid syntax) the procedure on the sys schema, which even as a sysadmin you can't do and will be presented with the error "The specified schema name "sys" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it."
